# OSB: Analyzing memory of proxy service

Tags: weblogic12c, osb

I have multiple proxies in a message flow.Is there a way in OSB by which I can monitor the memory utilization of each proxy ? I'm getting OOM, want to investigate which proxy is eating away all/most memory.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting OOME then it's either because a proxy is not freeing up all the memory it uses (so will eventually fail even with one request at a time), or you use too much memory per invocation and it dies over a certain threshold but is fine under low load. Do you know which it is?

Either way, you will want to [generate a heap dump](http://middlewaresnippets.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/dealing-with-out-of-memory-errors.html) on OOME so you can investigate what's going on. It's annoying but sometimes necessary. A colleague had to do that recently to fix some issues (one problem was an SB-transport platform bug, one was a thread starvation issue due to a platform work manager bug, the last one due to a Muxer bug when used in exalogic).

If it just performs poorly under load, then you'll need to do the usual OSB optimisations, like use fewer Assign steps (but assign more variables per step), do a lot more in xquery rather than proxy steps, *especially* loops that don't need a service callout, since they can easily be rolled into a `for` loop in xquery; you know, all the [standard stuff](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/core.1111/e10108/osb.htm#autoId16).

Comment: Thanks Trent for your reply.

Comment: I think mine is the first case - proxy is not freeing up all the memory it uses. Let me throw some light on what I'm trying to achieve. - Request comes in --> start recursion in proxy [ Read records from db (say 10,000) --service callOut--> Translate each record in loop---service callOut-->Write each record to file in loop ].All read,translate and write are handled in different proxies.So, at a time, there will be only 10,000 records (say - 400 MB) in memory, in each iteration, in each proxy(read,translate,write).Total records in table is 1,00,000 .Heap is 8GB . Thanks !

Comment: 10,000 records is still a big batch size (specified in JCA connector?), especially when you consider the size of context variables in each pipeline, on each side of the service callout.Have you tried seeing whether batch size of 10 causes the same issues?

Comment: I'm using xquery to create sql and fire db request within xquery due to certain design consideration. The batch size is part of sql ( ROWNUM >start(1) and  ROWNUM < (end)10000 ).start and end variable will change in each iteration, till end = 1,00,000.I need to test it with batch of 10.What I'm not able to understand is - why memory is not getting released after each iteration (readDB --> translate-->write). I think , creating thread and heap dump is the only option.

Comment: To be honest, that's the kind of thing I'd seriously consider doing async using JMS.

Comment: Thanks Trent. Async can't be used here for certain technical constraint (Scheduler expects a sync response in our case). I finally resolved by keeping everything in body variable,no duplication of  data in multiple variables.